# Fortran formated output for floating point numbers

Tags: excel, localization, fortran, output

Is there a way in Fortran to write float numbers as `17,3` and not `17.3`, changing the dot to a comma?

I have some large data sets wirtten to a .csv by a subroutine, and i want to do some Excel on it. The german version of Excel uses `.` as a seperator in floating point numbers. I know i can use the import feature to handle it, or use Nodepad++ to search and replace `.` with `,`. 
But i do generate lots of these files, and the subroutine will be used by others, so an Excel ready file would be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're just writing a line or two you can add the decimal edit descriptor `dc` to your output format.  Here's a simple example

```
write(*,'(dc,f12.3)') 12.3
```

which produces

```
12,300
```

If you want to write to a file, add the clause

```
decimal = 'comma'
```

to your `open` statement, for example:

```
open(6,decimal='comma')
```

Of course, here I'm (re-)opening stdout to write commas rather than points.