# Change value separators and decimal point characters on input

Tags: fortran

I have to read a file like this:

```
Text ooooppppopopopopopopp
opopopopopo
opopopopopo"
1;2,3;6,8;0,25;4
2;22,3;6,8;0,25;6
3;5,3;6,8;0,25,4;23
4;9,3;6,8;0,25;50
```

where `,` is the decimal separator, and `;` is the value separator

I do not care about the text between `"`.
How can I give the instructions to change the `,` by `;` as value separator, and `.` by `,` as decimal point?

Comment: Do yo have any code to illustrate how you are reading it? Wouldn't it be easier just to change your file?

Comment: Here's the ansver about decimal separator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117216/fortran-formated-output-for-floating-point-numbers/21117594#21117594

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to use a tool such as `sed` to modify your file before trying to read it with Fortran.

Comment: Compiling file: main.f95
C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\main.F95(11) : error 516 - DECIMAL is not a recognised keyword in OPEN
Compilation failed. This is because the program version I have??

Comment: Decimal is Fortran 2003. You didn't specify  your compiler vendor, so it is hard to tell which version you may need.

Comment: Thanks! I did it using "decimal=`comma`" with Geany